# Blackscreen after accessing SD Card - Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mount, lenovo, 19.10, sd-card

I do have an issue with my laptop (using Ubuntu 19.04) and my SD Card.

My laptop (Lenovo MIIX 320-10ICR) has an SD card slot, and if I put in the SD card everything seems to work, it does get mounted, but if I interact with the SD card in any way the screen turns black and I can't do anything anymore.

So the only workaround is that I take out the SD and put back the SD card holder into the laptop which removes the black screen.

So what kind of error is that? Why does the laptop turn the screen black if I access the SD card? It does get mounted but I can't access the card itself since it causes a black screen that can only be deactivated by taking the card out.

Comment: I personally wouldn't worry about it for now; Ubuntu 19.04 reaches EOL on Thursday (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2020-January/000252.html), so I'd focus on that and plan *release-upgrade* to bump yourself to 19.10 and then assess it there.  I can't see this issue impacting an upgrade, but with a newer software stack & some luck it may be gone post-upgrade.  *It reads to me like a hardware (PSU failing?) issue but I'm guessing*

Comment: so here's the deal. Upgraded to 19.10, everything works as intended expect for the sd card. The laptop still changes to a black screen when i insert the sd card (which does get mounted) and try to access it.

Comment: I would suggest editing your question and changing references of 19.04 to 19.10 given that's where you are now, as the only questions me & many are interested in regards 19.04 is problems with upgrading..  For your actual issue it sounds like a possibly iffy PSU, or faulty SD reader drawing beyond-spec power, which I'd firstly confirm by booting a very different OS or two (ie. a 'live' system) to confirm issue occurs there.. If it does it's not a Ubuntu config issue but hardware, if it only occurs in Ubuntu - it's likely a config issue in Ubuntu or kernel; try Ubuntu with 4.15 etc